# Java Collection - ArrayList and Linkedist

Tags: collections

> Which is better used for cache based application among Arraylist or
>   Linkedlist and why?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the ArrayList. More often than not, there is a better alternative to using a LinkedList, though there *are* scenarios where LinkedLists are the right choice.

Why?
LinkedLists use many small chunks of memory, which ends up offering very poor performance due to cache's utilization of locality.